# How get a URI with this format content://xx.xxx.xxx.file_provider/file%253A%2...etc

Tags: android, path, uri, intentfilter

How can I get an URI with this format?

**content://xx.xxx.xxx.file_provider/file%253A%252F%252F%252Fstorage%252Femulated%252F0%252FDownload%252FSync%252FFileName%252F%252FEYV.pdf**

I've seen several apps that open files with this URI through Intent so it can point to real file on device. So far I'm only getting the common format

**content://xx.xxx.xxx.fileprovider/external/Download/Sync/FileName.pdf**

Comment: "How can I get an URI with this format?" -- you can't, in general. "So far I'm only getting the common format" -- what is wrong with it? If you wish to share content with other apps, use `FileProvider`.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare the problem I'm facing is that when trying to save changes to a PDF document opened with this URI, any change I make is not saving after closing the document. The changes are saved in the copy made by the File Provider not in the original file. But when I use sample apps that create the other URI the changes are saved successfully.

Comment: "The changes are saved in the copy made by the File Provider not in the original file" -- `FileProvider` does not make a copy.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare but you are not answering my question nor helping me to solve my problem. Now you know the issue so if you have any suggestion I'd appreciate the help. I'm opening the file with Intents

Comment: "but you are not answering my question nor helping me to solve my problem" -- you  might wish to start over with a fresh question, where you provide a [mcve] and where you explain your symptoms in detail. You are guessing as to where your problem comes from, and I am pointing out that your guesses may not be correct.

Comment: There it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365349/open-pdf-doc-with-intent-is-not-saving-after-close-android