# Android - Open PDF Doc with Intent is not saving after close

Tags: java, android, pdf, kotlin

the problem I'm facing is that when trying to save changes to a PDF document opened with this URI
**content://xx.xxx.xxx.fileprovider/external/Download/Sync/FileName.pdf**, any change I make is not saving after closing the document. But when I use sample apps that create another format of URI like this one **content://xx.xxx.xxx.file_provider/file%253A%252F%252F%252Fstorage%252Femulated%252F0%252FDownload%252FSync%252FFileName%252F%252FEYV.pdf** the changes are saved successfully. I have also tried with **ACTION_EDIT**

```
    val file = File(fileModel.path)

    val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
          FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity?.applicationContext!!, "$APP_ID.fileprovider", file)
    } else {
          Uri.fromFile(file)
    }

    val mime = activity?.applicationContext!!.contentResolver.getType(uri)

    val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)

    val packageManager = activity?.applicationContext?.packageManager
    val activities = packageManager!!.queryIntentActivities(pdfIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

    for (resolvedIntentInfo in activities) {
        val packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        activity?.applicationContext?.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        activity?.applicationContext?.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    }

    if (pdfIntent.resolveActivity(activity!!.packageManager) != null) {
        //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent, "Open"))
        startActivity(pdfIntent)
    }
```

Comment: If you are opening your PDF for editing and it's not saving what you have changed that problem is not your own app. May third party apps not providing this type of functionality.

Comment: Thanks @PratikButani but I´ve some apps installed that open PDF and the changes are saved. The difference I saw is that those apps are sending other kind of URI to the intent

Comment: Its nothing else but encoded URI. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @PratikButani please read the question carefully.

Comment: `The difference I saw is that those apps are sending other kind of URI to the intent ` ???? Your app is using an intent to send an uri (of a pdf file) to an external app. And now you tell that that external app is sending an uri to an intent? What would that be? I do not grab that scenario.

Comment: What are the versions of the libraries you are using?

Comment: Hi @Boris    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    ext.koin_version = '2.0.1'
    ext.kotlin_coroutines_version = '1.3.3'
    // RxJava
    ext.rxAndroidVersion = "2.1.1"
    ext.rxJavaVersion = "2.1.3"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0"

Comment: @FantomasMex can you please check the following link. It might be helpful. developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/… Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE) If this helps you, let me know so that I can submit it as an answer for your approval.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file) and let me know if it helps.

```
// Request code for selecting a PDF document.
const val PICK_PDF_FILE = 2

fun openFile(pickerInitialUri: uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the file that should appear in the
        // system file picker when it loads.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PDF_FILE)
}
```

Also, for editing any document [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#edit) might help.

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

private fun alterDocument(uri: Uri) {
    try {
        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")?.use {
            FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use {
                it.write(
                    ("Overwritten at ${System.currentTimeMillis()}\n")
                        .toByteArray()
                )
            }
        }
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```